# Remove namespace prefix with sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I want to convert this piece of xml:

```
<v1:table>
  <v1:tr>
    <v1:td>Apples</v1:td>
    <v1:td>Bananas</v1:td>
  </v1:tr>
</v1:table>
```

into the following by removing the namespace prefixes (i.e. `v1`) and get the following by using **sed**:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT**: I also want to state that the xml is kept in a file.

Comment: No, it's impossible using `sed`: `sed` is based on regular expressions, and XML isn't a regular language. Consider using a genuine XML parser. You may see answers giving you snippets that will _seem_ to work on your specific toy example, but it would be very easy to forge a (valid XML) file on which it fails.

Comment: You don't want to remove the namespaces. Stop trying.  Explain what you really want to achieve (or why you think that removing the namespaces would help you).

Comment: I want to convert xml to a java class using Spring Framework's [XStreamMarshaller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/xstream/XStreamMarshaller.html). In order to have exact the same tags as the class fields, I want to get rid of the prefixes. I use only bash and sed before running the Spring batch, that's why I am inclined to use sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed works for your example:

```
sed -E 's~(</?)v1:~\1~g' file

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However just a note that `sed` is not the best tool for parsing HTML/XML. Consider using HTML parsers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you could do it with `hxpipe` and `hxunpipe` from the [W3C HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Status.html#HTML-XML-utils) ([packaged](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/html-xml-utils/) [for](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/30526438/dir/redhat_el_6/com/html-xml-utils-6.9-12.1.x86_64.rpm.html) [many](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/html-xml-utils) [distributions](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/html-xml-utils)):

```
$ hxpipe infile | sed 's/^\([()]\)v1:/\1/g' | hxunpipe
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`hxpipe` parses XML/HTML and turns it into an awk/sed-friendly line based format:

```
$ hxpipe infile
(v1:table
-\n  
(v1:tr
-\n    
(v1:td
-Apples
)v1:td
-\n    
(v1:td
-Bananas
)v1:td
-\n  
)v1:tr
-\n
)v1:table
-\n
```

where lines starting with `(` and `)` are opening and closing tags, so removing the first `v1:` from lines starting with `(` or `)` (which is what the sed command above does) achieves the desired effect. Notice that text lines start with a `-`, so there can't be any false positives.